# Package io.core.micrometer.core does not exist error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-micrometer

I'm trying to use the @Timed annotation to measure time taken by a method. These are the config changes I've done so far.

Dependencies in my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':data-access')

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'

implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: '3.0.0'

// loggers
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.30'

// utils
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.4'

// swagger
implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '3.0.0'

implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-dynamodb', version: '1.11.664'
implementation group: 'io.github.boostchicken', name: 'spring-data-dynamodb', version: '5.2.1'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-commons', version: '2.5.0'

implementation group: 'com.timgroup', name: 'java-statsd-client', version: '3.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.11.4'
implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.11.4'
implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.11'
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.5.2'
implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus', version: '1.7.1'
implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-core', version: '1.7.1'

testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.3.8.RELEASE'
```

}

Application

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.xyz.app"})
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
        return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }
}
```

Service

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class QueryClient {

    private final Properties properties;

    private APIClientConfig openAPIClientConfig;

    @Autowired
    private Util util;

    @Timed("QUERY")
    public String query(String actorId, String reqMsgId) throws Exception {
```

This is the error that I'm getting

```
error: package io.micrometer.core.annotation does not exist
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
                                    ^

 @Timed("QUERY")
     ^
  symbol:   class Timed
  location: class QueryClient
```

The configuration looks alright to me based on what I've seen online. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well for starters your dependencies are a mess. Mixing versions of Spring Boot is trouble waiting to happen. Depending on your, actual used, version of Spring Boot the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` already includes the micrometer dependency.